# How to Get Selected Cell Value InTextBox

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox and a GridView. I have made a column in gridview as a linkbutton. I want that when I click a linkbutton I get that link button text value in my textbox.

My gridview is shown below-

[image]

I want When I click **test5** my textbox1.text = test5 and so on..

How can I do this ?

Comment: dear check the bellow answer it will help you if you need any other held just tell me or show me you code aspx and aspx.cs code then i will give answer according to your code :)

Comment: dear just post your code

Comment: @Developerzz I got a solution. Deepak Joshi's code is working for me. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: nice dear good best of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add commandname in gridview link column as below

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="lnklink" CommandName="displayLink" />
```

And add the "RowCommand" event on gridview like below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDemo" runat="server
onrowcommand="gvDemo_RowCommand" />


protected void gvDemo_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "displayLink")
    {   
       textbox1.text=((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this both in asp as well as using client side technologies like JQUERY javascript etc, I will suggest you to use jquery since keeping such things in client side will help you improve the performance

Now when u create a grid /repeater etc ultimately .net renders it into simple html controls, and jquery or client side technologies just work over this html , here is a small example with simple html

**> HTML**

```
My data : <input type="Text" id="TxtBox"/> //in .net id u have to take care by using .clientid property
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td  width="50">
            SOmething
        </td>
        <td  width="50">
            <a href="#" class="someName" >LINK1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td  width="50">
            SOmething2
        </td>
        <td  width="50">
            <a href="#" class="someName" >LINK2</a>   //class name is important since thats what we  are going deal with
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td  width="50">
            SOmething3
        </td>
        <td  width="50">
            <a href="#"  class="someName">LINK3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(".someName").on("click","",function(){
       $("#TxtBox").val($(this).text());
    });
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/AmarnathRShenoy/Hw4UG/

Comment: i make you plus one coz its also nice solution but dear he just tag asp.net and gridview so answer him according to his tags thank's

Comment: @AzharShahid i gues u havent added Jquery reference to your page

Comment: @AzharShahid There is nothing called not working:-) , Dont forget to add jquery to your page and ids and classes, and it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

create RowCommand event for grid and then do the following code

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "test")
    {
        textbox1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
}
```

and for aspx page do the following in your linkbutton

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbtn" runat="server" Text="test5" CommandArgument="test5" CommandName="test" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

or if you are binding your database table column to your linkbutton then do the following

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbtn" runat="server" Text='<% yourcolumname %>' CommandArgument='<% yourcolumname %>' CommandName="test" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```